# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: listing.owner is undefined when trying to submit

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have this JavaScript with Rails app I am working on, and when I try to submit a new property listing form with a new owner I just created, it will not let me submit the form, but will only let me submit the form with the new owner selected after I refresh the page. I keep getting a **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: listing.owner is undefined** message in my console when trying to submit the new property listing with new owner freshly created.

**FYI: I am not allowed to use ERB on this project**

My code so far:
This is the form I use to create a new property owner

```
  <form id = "owner_form">
        <div>
          <label for='name'>Owner Name:</label>
          <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder="John Doe" >
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for='phone_number'>Phone Number:</label>
          <input type='text' id='phone_number' name='phone_number' placeholder="Phone Number" >
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for='real_estate_agent'>Listing Agent:</label>
          <input type='text' id='real_estate_agent' name='real_estate_agent' placeholder="Agent">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type='submit' id='owner_submit' value='Submit'/>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Then once I submit the owner creation form it dynamically drops the new owner in a  drop down I have setup in my property listing from by a GET fetch method

```
<form id = "listing_form">
      <div>
        <label for='name'>Owner Name:</label>
        <select id='owner_id' name='owner_id' >
          
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for='address'>Street Address:</label>
        <input type='text' id='address' name='address' placeholder="123 Elm Street">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for='state'>State:</label><br>
        <input type='text' id='state' name='state' placeholder="Texas">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for='sale_price'>Listing Price:</label><br>
        <input type='text' id='sale_price' name='sale_price' placeholder="$500,000">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type='submit' id='prop_submit'  value='Submit'/>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**Then I attached listForm node to a addEventListener**

```
listForm.addEventListener('submit',(event) =>{
      // event.preventDefault()
      
      const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

      fetch(PROPERTIES_URL,{
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body: formData
      }).then(res => res.json()).then((list_data) => {
        
        let new_listing = renderListing(list_data)
        listForm.reset()
        listings.append(new_listing)
        
        console.log(list_data)
      })
  })
```

The issue here is I keep getting this **'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: listing.owner is undefined'** when I submit the form to create a new property listing that is preventing a new listing with that newly created owner.

The code this is referencing to is this:

```
const showListCard = (listing) => {
   
    return `<p>Address: ${listing.address}</p>
            <p>State: ${listing.state}</p>
            <p>Sale Price: ${listing.sale_price}</p>
            <p>Owner: ${listing.owner.name}</p>`
      }


     
     const renderListing = (listing) => {
  let listingCard = document.createElement('div')
  listingCard.setAttribute('class','card')
  listingCard.dataset.id = listing.id
  listingCard.innerHTML = showListCard(listing)
  //---Delete Button
  let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
  deleteBtn.setAttribute('id','delete')
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'Delete Listing'
  deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    let listingId = parseInt(event.target.dataset.listingId)
    event.target.parentNode.remove()
    deleteListing(listingId)
  })
  listingCard.appendChild(deleteBtn)
  
  return listings.appendChild(listingCard)
  
  
  
}
```

Also here is the back-end rails code

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :properties
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner
    
end

#property listing create action in properties controller
def create
    
        property = Property.create(prop_params)
         prop_params[:owner_id] = :owner.id
        if property.save
            render json: property
        else
            render json: { error: "Couldn't save"}
        end
    end

    private
    def prop_params
        params.permit(:id,:address, :state, :sale_price, :owner_id)
    end

#owner create action in owners controller
     def create
            
            @owner = Owner.create(owner_params)

            if @owner.save
                render json: @owner
            end
        

    end

    private 
    def owner_params
        params.permit(:id,:name,:phone_number,:real_estate_agent)
    end
```

I tired associating on creation in my **create action** for my back-end prop_params[:owner_id] = @owner.id, but that has not been working out for me. What can I do to resolve the 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: listing.owner is undefined' I mentioned above?

**Update**
Adding entire properties controller

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_owner, only: [:create,:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
        Property.new
    end


    def index
        properties = Property.all
        render json: properties
    end


    def show
        property = Property.find(params[:id])
        options = {
            include: [:owner]
        }
        render json: property
    end

    def create
       byebug
        property = Property.create(prop_params)
         
        if property.save
            render json: property
        else
            render json: { error: "Couldn't save"}
        end
    end

    def destroy
        property = Property.find(params[:id])
        unless property.nil?
          property.destroy
          render json: property
        else
          render json: { error: "Property not found" }, status: 404
        end
      end

    private

    def set_owner
        @owner = Owner.find(params[:owner_id])
    end

    
    def prop_params
        params.(:owner).permit(:id,:address, :state, :sale_price, :owner_id)
    end

end
```

Comment: Do the other fields get populated? I.e, can you see `Address: <address>` etc?

Comment: @Ibz yes they do. I forgot to show an example from my JSON file to show all the fields. I was cutting down on my showListCard function to focus on at least displaying my the owner name.

Comment: Is there any chance you can breakpoint into this function when it's giving you that error? `const showListCard = (listing) => {
   
    return '<p>Address: ${listing.address}</p>
            <p>State: ${listing.state}</p>
            <p>Sale Price: ${listing.sale_price}</p>
            <p>Owner: ${listing.owner.name}</p>'
      }`. I want to see what if being passed into the function

Comment: Here is what the debugger was first giving me. I was trying to get what I was currently entering listing = {id: 1, address: "100 Elm Street", state: "Tx", sale_price: "$600000", owner_id: 1, …}

Comment: Actually hold on

Comment: @Ibz So.....I put beybug into my property create action in my properties controller on backend.....and the owner_id attribute comes back as a string name, instead of an actual integer id

Comment: @Ibz it won't let me copy and paste it in here but when I put in prop_params[:owner_id] it returns a string and not an integer for my owner_id attribute.

Comment: Yeah ok, sounds reasonable. The problem is that you need to be returning the owner object back with the listing. At the moment, it's just sending back the owner id. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Ibz honestly no. Its something I've been tackling for the past couple of days

Comment: Haha, that's fine. I haven't done any Ruby Rails for quite a while and I'm trying to quickly cast my mind back to how it should be done. I think I remember? I'll post what I'm thinking as an answer so that the formatting will be reasonable

Comment: I tried prop_params[:owner_id] = @owner.id but that doesn't sound like what you are talking about.

Comment: Yeah, that's the bit I'm referring to, but there's a way to make it actually return the owner object, I'll put an answer now

Comment: Thanks, I need all the help I can get. This is like the only thing I have before I move on, lol

Answer (score 0):

So, if I remember correctly, you need to tell the controller that it needs to first fetch another object. In your case, it needs to first fetch the owner before returning the response.

In your property controller, the file needs to start with something like:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_owner, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

This lets the controller know that before sending the response back for :show, :edit, :update or :delete, it needs to first do the set_owner method. You can adjust the values in the array so that it only calls the function whevener you need it. In your case, it's probably only :show and :edit that you want.

And near the bottom of the file, in the private methods, you need something like:

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_owner
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:owner_id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def prop_params
  params.require(:owner).permit(:id, :address, :state, :sale_price)
end
```

I'm hoping that's all? Please comment if it's still not working, I'm trying to re-acquaint myself with this all! Ruby Rails is definitely not my favorite web framework

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224277/discussion-on-answer-by-ibz-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-listing-owner-is-un).